# Compile non-modular code that depends on modules

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have a folder with two compiled modules `simple-modules/module1` and  `simple-modules/module2` these contained exploded code, so not its jar and both modules contain a `module-info.java`

I have other non-modular **source** code in folder `normal-java-packages` that uses the API exposed by the mentioned modules.

So, as a first step I would like to compile that.

Reading: https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-artifacts

As far as I understand, the code in `normal-java-packages` should be part of the classpath, so it will be included in the `unnamedmodule`, and it will able to access all JRE modules as well as my user-defined modules `simple-modules/module1` and `simple-modules/module2`.

I am trying to run:

```bash
javac -p simple-modules -d output  -cp normal-java-packages
```

However, it looks like something is off as I get:
`error: no source files`

Any suggestions or pointers on what may be the issue here?

**EDIT**:

Also tried this command as suggested:

```
javac -p simple-modules -d output classpath_entry/com/myuser/modules/main/MainApp.java
```

Getting these errors:

```
classpath_entry/com/myuser/modules/main/MainApp.java:3: error: package com.myuser.hello is not visible
import com.myuser.hello.HelloModules;
                   ^
  (package com.myuser.hello is declared in module hellomodule, which is not in the module graph)
classpath_entry/com/myuser/modules/main/MainApp.java:4: error: package com.myuser.greetings is not visible
import com.myuser.greetings.EnglishGreeting;
                   ^
  (package com.myuser.greetings is declared in module hellomodule, which is not in the module graph)
classpath_entry/com/myuser/modules/main/MainApp.java:5: error: package com.myuser.other is not visible
import com.myuser.other.Other;
                   ^
  (package com.myuser.other is declared in module greetings, which is not in the module graph)
3 errors
```

So it looks like the compiled exploded modules in `simple-modules` are not visible, any idea why ?

Comment: Your use of `-cp` is wrong if you want to compile code in normal-java-packages as it specifies the class path (i.e. already compiled code). Also, Java expects you to specify individual classes or wildcards to compile sources, not just a directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I will answer my own question as I found out what the issue is:

the command to use is:

```
javac -p simple-modules -d output --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH classpath_entry/com/myuser/modules/main/MainApp.java
```

I still find a bit redundant the `--add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH`
The JRE modules are loaded fine without it, I don't see why we need it even when we are already specifying the user defined modules in the module path `-p` already.